# Prove that $ \sum_1^3 x_i^4+\sum_1^3 x_i^6\le?$ when $\sum_1^3 x_i^2=3$

Tags: inequality

Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_1^3 x_i^4+\sum_1^3 x_i^6\le k$ when $\displaystyle\sum_1^3 x_i^2=3$.Find k.

---

$$\begin{align}
\sum_i^3x_i^4
&=\left(\sum_i^3x_i^2\right)^2-2\sum_{i,j\ne i}^3x_i^2xj^2\\
&=9-2\sum_{i,j\ne i}^3x_ixj\\
\sum_i^3x_i^6
&=\left(\sum_i^3x_i^2\right)\left(\sum_i^3x_i^4-\sum_{i,j\ne i}^3x_i^2x_j^2\right)+3\prod_i^3x_i^2\\
&=3\left(9-3\sum_{i,j\ne i}^3x_ixj\right)+3\prod_i^3x_i^2\end{align}$$
I can't reduce $\displaystyle \sum x_i^2x_j^2$ and $\displaystyle \prod x_i^2$
And tried using AM-GM which doesn;t give any upper bound instead the lower one.

---

**NOTE:** Use only **AM-GM/Rearraangement/Chebyshev/Holder/Cauchy/Schur**

Comment: "It is intuitively clear that the upper bound will be n when all variables are equal to 1." Actually this case yields the **lower** bound. The upper bound is $n^\lambda$, rather.

Comment: Expand $(\sum x_i^2)^{\lambda}$. You get $\sum x_i^{2\lambda}$ plus a lot of other terms which are all positive.

Comment: $x^4(1+x^2)$ is a convex function, hence $\sum x_i^4(1+x_i^2)$ attains its maximum on the boundary - on the other hand, the listed inequalities have stationary points inside the domain.

Comment: You have significantly changed the question. Furthermore, in keeping with your previous question, did you mean $$\sum_{i=1}^3x_i^2=3$$ on the right?

Comment: @robjohn edited

Comment: @Aditya: I have edited the title and question to match. If that is not what you intended, revert my edit.

Comment: @robjohn nope it's coreect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{2\lambda}\le\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\right)^\lambda\tag{1}
$$
since expanding the right side (using the [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)) gives the left side plus other non-negative terms.

Furthermore, suppose that $x_1=\sqrt{n}$ and $x_i=0$ for $i\ne1$. Then we have equality in $(1)$. Thus, $(1)$ is sharp. That is,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2=n\implies\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{2\lambda}\le n^\lambda\tag{2}
$$
is sharp.

---

**Second Version of the Question**

Using $(2)$, we have that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^3x_i^4+\sum_{i=1}^3x_i^6
&\le3^2+3^3\\
&=36\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Note that equality in $(3)$ is attained if we let $x_1=\sqrt3$ and $x_2=x_3=0$. Thus, $(3)$ is as good as one can get.

---

**Lower Bound**

The upper bound is gotten by looking at the boundary cases, while the lower bound is gotten by using Hölder's Inequality.

Applying Hölder, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^21^{1-1/\lambda}
&\le\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{2\lambda}\right)^{1/\lambda}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n1\right)^{1-1/\lambda}\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{2\lambda}\right)^{1/\lambda}\quad n^{1-1/\lambda}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
which implies
$$
n^{1-\lambda}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\right)^\lambda\le\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{2\lambda}\tag{5}
$$
That is,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2=n\implies n\le\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{2\lambda}\tag{6}
$$
for which equality holds if all $x_i=1$.

---

Therefore,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2=n\implies n\le\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{2\lambda}\le n^\lambda\tag{7}
$$
and each of these inequalities is sharp.

Applying $(7)$ to your specific case yields
$$
\sum_{i=1}^3x_i^2=3\implies6\le\sum_{i=1}^3x_i^4+\sum_{i=1}^3x_i^6\le36\tag{8}
$$

Comment: can you use this in the question/sorry for changing the ques

Comment: you mean sharpness in the sense?

Comment: In the sense that the inequality is true, and there is a possible condition where equality is attained.

Comment: can you add for other bound?

Comment: I don't understand. What other bound?

Comment: the lower one which comes n?maybe?

Comment: @Aditya [W&A says $36$ is the maximum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maximize%5B%7Bx%5E4+%2B+x%5E6+%2B+y%5E4+%2B+y%5E6+%2B+z%5E4+%2B+z%5E6%2C++++x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%2B+z%5E2+%3D%3D+3%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+y%2C+z%7D+%5D)

Comment: @FelixMarin: I added a section on the lower bound because I thought that was what Aditya was asking about. I could easily be mistaken.

Comment: $0$ k. That's fine. It was a nice answer. +1.